# "New" tab in "Tag info" section shows answers as questions (or the title is wrong)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are indeed 18k questions tagged with [wpf]. But that is not the title of the page. Look under **Tag Info** at the left. There it says **New answers tagged** `wpf` as subtitle.

[image]

Comment: I missed that, must say it's pretty confusing mixing the answers of different questions.